# How to use spring mvc controllers without component-scanning?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, classloader, spring-3, spring-annotations

I use Spring 3.x MVC @Controller annotations. My servlet.xml has this entry:

```
<context:component-scan base-package=”com.my.controllers.package”/>
```

My webapp, on Google's app engine has to initialize & startup within 60secs. Mine takes longer due to this classpath scanning (This [link explains](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) the importance of "**Reducing or Avoiding the Use of Component Scanning**" in app engine).

I added the following line to my servlet.xml

```
    <bean id=”myComponentBean” class=”org.foo.MyComponent”/>
```

Now, regardless of whether I add @Controller or not, the controller does not get loaded. Any url results in 404.

**Questions:**

1) So how do I make a spring 3.x MVC controller behave as a web controller without relying on the comonent scanning?

2) When I filed a bug with google, I was asked to remove the "component scanning" & to "explicitly define the classes needed using classLoader.getResource()". How can I use classLoader.getResource() to load mvc controllers?

P.S: Classpath scanning on app engine has known issues. Discussing that will be a digression here. So I skipped the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are already doing it right. define your controllers with `<bean class="..." />` and put `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your servlet configuration. that is it!

**UPDATE:**

and you may need `<context:annotation-config />` as well for some annotations(`@EJB`, `@PersistenceContext`, etc.) to get handled by spring.